# ng-show element is visible even though the expression evaluates to false

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

This one has got me stumped. It was working last week and suddenly stopped working. An element I have ng-show on is visible even though it's evaluating as false.

In the script:

```
$scope.alerts = { message: '', success: false, error: false, notice: false };
```

In the markup:

```
<div class="alert success" ng-show="alerts.success">
    <strong>SUCCESS!</strong>
    <div>{{alerts.message}}</div>
</div>
```

For testing purposes, I placed a {{alerts.success}} in the markup to make sure it is indeed evaluating to false, and i can confirm that it is.

Any idea why this would happen?

ps: Unfortunately, I can't post more code than this.

Comment: Can you not make a minimal plunker that shows the problem?

Comment: are you sure, alerts.success is not 'false' of string and not boolean.. ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's a boolean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, this is a known problem (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4394) with version 1.2. We introduced ng-csp into our project last week and it doesn't play well with ng-show/hide. I added the css snippet below which I got from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/w00KgEi1DLk and it works fine now. Thanks for your responses!

```
@charset "UTF-8";

[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak],
.ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak,
.ng-hide {
  display: none !important;
}

ng\:form {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have written `$scope.alerts.success = false;` inside a callback function. Yes, the value of $scope.alerts.success will become false, as it will properly show in `{{alerts.success}}` in your markup.

To combat this, you'll need to wrap $scope.$apply around the variable assignment statement:

```
SomeService.DoSomething(function success() { /* Success Code */}, 
     function error() {
          $scope.$apply(function() {
              $scope.alerts.success = false;
          });
     })
);
```

Angular isn't exactly fully automatic with data bainding. Yes, it did update the value in the variable, but it didn't automatically update the UI. When you change a value inside a callback (including setTimeout), you must wrap your value-assigning code with $scope.$apply so that Angular will update the UI.

Comment: It's not in a callback function. It's just sitting on the top level of a controller function.

Comment: You can also try to put the success property as an immediate 'property' of $scope, $scope.success = false;. Then, in your markup, you write ng-show="success". those ng-attributes tend to like immediate properties of $scope better than 'grandchildren properties'.

Answer (score 0):

Something else must be happening in your code. ng-show is capable of checking object properties.

Here is a working plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/QliAbg7zfkWgTVUTuLVp?p=preview

Comment: Yes, it was something else. See my answer. Thanks for the plunker. Much appreciated.